# Trigger debounce function two times independently

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, debouncing

I have declared 'service':

```
// myService.js
export default {
  someService: _.debounce(
    function  someService(rule, value, callback) {
      myApi.get(
        `check-input/${value}`,
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.valid) {
          callback();
        } else {
          callback(new Error('Invalid value'));
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        callback(new Error('Internal error. Please try later.'));
      });
  },2000)};
```

I would like to use this service two times independently at the same time.

I'm calling this service like this:

```
const ValidatorA = (rule, value, callback) => {
  const serviceA = myService.someService(rule, value, callback);
  return serviceA;
};

const ValidatorB = (rule, value, callback) => {
  const serviceB = myService.someService(rule, value, callback);
  return serviceB;
};
```

`ValidatorA` and `ValidatorB` are linked to different inputs in template and runs almost at the same time. (1s delay)

What I would like to achieve is that `ValidatorA` and `ValidatorB` will call `myService.someService` independently, so there should be two calls at the same time. Currently it calls only once (from `ValidatorB` as it is called one second later). I suppose that `ValidatorB` is overwritting call from `ValidatorA`.

Creating two the same methods is solving this problem, however I believe that there is more elegant solution. `Object.assign` or `_deepClone` is not solving problem either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap `someServices` in a function

```
export default {
    getServices: function() {
      return 
        _.debounce(
        function  someService(rule, value, callback) {
          myApi.get(
            `check-input/${value}`,
          )
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.valid) {
              callback();
            } else {
              callback(new Error('Invalid value'));
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            callback(new Error('Internal error. Please try later.'));
          });
      },2000)
     }
};
```

and then

```
const ValidatorA = (rule, value, callback) => {
  const serviceA = myService.getServices()(rule, value, callback);
  return serviceA;
};

const ValidatorB = (rule, value, callback) => {
  const serviceB = myService.getServices()(rule, value, callback);
  return serviceB;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting  `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__mixins_myService__.a.getServices(...) is not a function`

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: import getServices from '../mixins/myService';

Comment: It is not working either :( `TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function` Thank you for your effort!!!

Comment: It's weird. I'm changing again. Hope it will be ok this time